Multi-classification of Text using NLP python - Recall is relatively very less for 2 categories out of total categories
I am having almost balanced dataset of 9 unique categories, each having almost 2200 rows with difference of +/-100 rows. To create model , i have used below mentioned urls approach but in each case my model accuracy is coming around 58% and precision/recall is also around 54%. Can you please let me know what wrong am I doing?
https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-scikit-learn-12f1e60e0a9f
https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-multiclass-classification-with-imbalanced-data-set-29f6a177c1a
https://medium.com/@robert.salgado/multiclass-text-classification-from-start-to-finish-f616a8642538
My dataset is having only 2 columns , 1 as feature and other as label.
from pandas import ExcelFile

df = pd.read_excel('Prediction.xlsx', 
                   sheet_name='Sheet1')
df.head()
BAD_SYMBOLS_RE = re.compile('[^0-9a-z #+_]')
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install lxml

def clean_text(text):
    """
        text: a string

        return: modified initial string
    """
    text = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser").text # HTML decoding
    text = text.lower() # lowercase text
    text = REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE.sub(' ', text) # replace REPLACE_BY_SPACE_RE symbols by space in text
    text = BAD_SYMBOLS_RE.sub('', text) # delete symbols which are in BAD_SYMBOLS_RE from text
    text = ' '.join(word for word in text.split() if word not in STOPWORDS) # delete stopwors from text
    return text

df['notes_issuedesc'] = df['notes_issuedesc'].apply(clean_text)
print_plot(10)
df['notes_issuedesc'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(' '))).sum()
X = df.notes_issuedesc
y = df.final
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state = 42)
%%time
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

nb = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
               ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
               ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
              ])
nb.fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_pred = nb.predict(X_test)

print('accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred,target_names=my_tags))


Did you try looking at the code they provided? https://github.com/susanli2016/Machine-Learning-with-Python/blob/master/Consumer_complaints.ipynb and seeing if you have the same results?

Yes i have exactly followed same steps but my model accuracy is quite low- 58%.

So you ran it with the same dataset and you can replicate it, but now with your dataset it gives around 58%?

i have only used above urls approach for my own dataset. So I am seeking suggestions how to make it better.

Can you try to replicate their own data. Sometimes people report high percentages than expected. My guess without looking at your dataset, is that the variance and means between your 9 unique categories are close enough together that an SVM or random forest can barely differentiate between them

So what algorithm I should use for my dataset , recall is quite less for 2 categories , do i need to make some modifications in dataset for these 2 categories?

You did not post your code. Nor did you demonstrate that you followed the tutorial.

Added code , output of this is shown in attached image- My Precision-Recall-CategoryWise .

i was able to fix it with above code by correct my data, have performed few data wrangling operations and it generated with higher accuracy.

I was able to get my code to work by first correcting my data.
The issue was that there was lot of missing data, so I used mean values to fill these missing values. I also utilized a scatter chart to identify outlier data and then removed those as well.
I have performed few data wrangling operations and it generated with higher accuracy.

i am referring to my code which i have already added in original post. My code is correct but input data was faulty.

There was lot of missing data so used mean values to fill these missing values and secondly utilizing scatter chart identified outlier data and removed it.
